# Error Using RecyclerView and Fragment on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an app where I've a RecyclerView with the options to remove the  objects and add random numbers. What I'm trying to do is show a fragment when any member of the recycler view list is clicked. I'm getting the error "    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed".
I'm pretty shure I'm doing something very wrong.
What I tried to do is putting a call to the change fragment method on my AnimalsAdapter class. I'm letting the code below and a github link.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2, PID: 18705
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2114)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2.MainActivity.changeFragment(MainActivity.java:148)
    at com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2.AnimalsAdapter$1.onClick(AnimalsAdapter.java:81)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

My Code Main class changeFragment:

```
    public void changeFragment(View view){
    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    fragment = fragmentOne;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

FragmentOne class code:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstaceState){
    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,container,false);
}
```

}

Click Listener code:

```
        // Set a click listener for TextView
    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new MainActivity().changeFragment(view);
            //String animal = mDataSet.get(position);
            //Toast.makeText(mContext,animal,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

What I have to do to achieve the fragment when pressing the recyclerview member?

[Original code I'm using to try what I'm trying](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview-add-remove-item.html)

[Github link for complete project](https://github.com/gatesco/recyclerviewtp2)

Comment: you should create a call back in order to achieve your goal

Answer (score 1):

You should never instantiate your activity this way: `new MainActivity().changeFragment(view);`, it will never initialise properly. So it's either you delegate the listener, or find another work around for the callback.

For example, create an interface for callback:

```
interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v);
}
```

Let your MainActivity implements the interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, animalsList, this);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view) {
        changeFragment(view);
    }
}
```

Then allow your adapter to take `ItemClickListener` as a parameter:

```
private ItemClickListener callback;

public AnimalAdapter(Context context, List<String> data, ItemClickListener callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
```

And let your `holder.mTextView` to forward the callback (back to activity):

```
holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(callback::onItemClick);
```

Comment: Can you give me a hint of how I should implement other callback method?

Comment: @BernardoMorais I've posted an example in my answer.

Comment: I created the interface, put the second code and third code on the MainActivity and now I'm stuck with a "Cannot resolve symble "callback"" error on AnimalsAdapter. Did I put something in the wrong place?

Comment: @BernardoMorais That'd be my bad, sorry. I had a typo, try and change the variable name: `private ItemClickListener callback;` not ``private ItemClickListener listener;`

Comment: Now I have this error as soon as I open the app:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2, PID: 20254
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: That doesn't appear to be relevant to the changes, where did you call `.size()`?

Comment: @BernardoMorais I just checked your code in your GitHub, I'm pretty sure you can safely remove `notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mDataSet.size());` in your `AnimalAdapter`.

Comment: @BernardoMorais Actually, you just forgot to assign your field:  `mDataSet = data;` and `mContext = context;`. :/

Comment: Worked, but now when I click on the item to show the fragment I got this error: 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2, PID: 20692
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070042 (com.example.berna.recyclerviewtp2:id/fragment) for fragment FragmentOne{6af2928 #0 id=0x7f070042}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)

Comment: I changed fragmentOne for blank and worked now I have to implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: I guess you've just got to be cautious when it comes to refactoring, this solution is simply just showing you another way of implementing or receiving callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should create fragment after activity created, that is a basic knowledge about activity life cycle.

```
holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(your_current_activity, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

then replace fragment in `onCreate()` of MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
        changeFragment(null); //because we don't using parameter view
```

}

If you have any problem else, please comment below.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Cannot resolve method" on startActivity(intent);

Comment: where do you call it?  fragment ?

Comment: I tried to call it on the AnimalsAdapter:
 "public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
 ...
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                here
            }
    });"

Comment: @BernardoMorais: Aaron has the correct solution, try that way!

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes in your code.
1. Create an interface for click listener.
2. If you want to replace fragment then you need one more Layout in XML

We solve the first issue.
1. Create an interface for click listener.
Below are some change you need to do in your adapter,

- Create Interface in your adapter

  public interface RecyclerItemInteraction {
          void onChangeFragmentClick();
      }
- The second change will pass this interface.

  - Deeclare gloabal variable
    **private RecyclerItemInteraction mInteraction;**

    public AnimalsAdapter(Context context,List list,RecyclerItemInteraction interaction){
        mDataSet = list;
        mContext = context;
        mInteraction = interaction;
    }
- Replace this below line
  new MainActivity().changeFragment(view); : Remove it
  **if (mInteraction!=null)mInteraction.onChangeFragmentClick();** add this line.
- Now Go to your MainActivity and add below line
  **mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, animalsList,this);**
  You can see that add third parameter **this**.
- Now override this method and enjoy your day.

  @Override
      public void onChangeFragmentClick() {
          Fragment fragment;
          FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
          fragment = fragmentOne;
          FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
          ft.replace(R.id.container,fragment);
          ft.addToBackStack(null);
          ft.commit();
      }

  2. If you want to replace fragment then you need one more Layout in XML
- Add this line to your main_activity.xml layout.

Comment: This new interface file for recyclerview should be created in another class or inside AnimalsAdapter?

Comment: You can add in the adapter as well as create a new class. both things are work.